# can we have two <ion-nav> in an ionic 3 app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new to ionic.

I'm making an app(ionic 3) where initially I take users to login Page and after successful Login. I change the RootPage from the loginPage to MenuPage where I have `<ion-menu>` with one more `<ion-nav>`.
Now I have 2 `<ion-nav>`

1 -> in my app.html

2 -> in my menu.html

In my menu I have options and initially, it is set to *DashboardPage* which is loaded properly. When the options from the menu are clicked I'm trying to change the rootPage of `<ion-nav>` in *menu.html*

Now when I try to setRoot in menu.html I get an error `uncaught in promise ): invalid link homepage`

Note: I'm not using Lazyloading for any of the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question.
Hope it might be of some use to someone like me.

We can use two `<ion-nav>` in an app.

So for `<ion-nav>` in my *app.html* I'm using NavController to setRoot. And for my `<ion-nav>` in *menu.html* I'm Using Nav with `@ViewChild`

Coming to the error which I was getting it was because I'm not using Lazyloading so I have to call my pages in menu options without quotations.

Cheers